# (file) dependency tracking in Stata

Tags: r, stata, project-management

As much of empirical research (or data analysis) has become a major software development exercise, practitioners use more and more such tools. So far I am aware of researchers using project management, issue tracking and versioning tools (JIRA, GitHub) but I think there should be a system to track and analyze (e.g. build a graph it, also for plotting) which data files a project uses, and which other pieces of code it calls. Is such a tool in common use for R or Stata?

I know that the major straight-up development tools for this are Maven, Ivy, and Gradle. But they do not seem to support R or Stata. What could one use for our use case? (This is why this question is on CV and not SO.)

Comment: For Stata I've used `project` from SSC for some time, and works wonderfully. For general purpose see GNU Make. One reference is http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/make3/book/index.csp. (I'm not sure this is on-topic here.)

Comment: Why not just write a little wrapper to scan for ".dta" files in directories and subdirectories, and then scan for references in the ".do" files. Output this data to a txt file and archive it in the Github account. Then when you see the line-by-line, you can verify if things were created or destroyed, broken links, etc.

Comment: @AdamO That's great in theory. I think Gentzkow and Shapiro have a little Python script doing basically this. But I think they also wanted to start using a proper tool for this soon, and I just don't know which one they could mean.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a fully automated system but [Hans-Martin von Gaudecker at Bonn](https://www.iame.uni-bonn.de/people/hm-gaudecker) is an evangelist for doing this with [waf](https://github.com/waf-project/waf), a Python-based build system that allows you to specify dependencies between files and only rebuilds what has changed since the last run or is downstream from such a change. It's pretty language agnostic. His [templates](https://github.com/hmgaudecker/econ-project-templates) support Python, R, Matlab and Stata out of the box and there's experimental support for Julia. As an added bonus, it automatically runs non-dependent tasks in parallel.